# How to use Computer as a HeadSet using a bluetooth dongle paired with Android phone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, android

My goal is simple. Whenever someone makes a called on my phone I want to be able to use my computer as a headset. This way I could use my Mic to talk back at the person on the other end, and my headphones to listen.

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 15.10, and using a bluetooth dongle 4.0

Progress.. I have no problems pairing my phone with my computer, nor any issue with sending files over the bluetooth connection. The phone, however, doesn't see the computer during calls.

Anyone out there knows what to do?

Comment: There are some interesting pointers in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/852687/668742 "this answer"). So far I have been able to stream audio from my phone to my PC.