# I want to use my Lubuntu 16.04 as bluetooth speakers for my Android phone

Tags: sound, lubuntu, bluetooth, android, headset

I want my Lubuntu to play my Android ringtone when my Lubuntu is paired over Bluetooth whit my Android phone.

I was able to make my Lubuntu play music and video sounds from my Android, whit Blueman-applet, but when it should play ringtone when someone is calling me, it only plays on my phone speakers, but not on my Lubuntu.

I know this is kinda duplicate question, but since I found no answer there, I ask here, and hope someone will help me, and many more people that need this help.

Here is duplicate: [How to use Computer as a HeadSet using a bluetooth dongle paired with Android phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727794/how-to-use-computer-as-a-headset-using-a-bluetooth-dongle-paired-with-android-ph)

Here is another question: https://www.facebook.com/groups/lubuntu.official/permalink/1160833463973472/

Answer (score -1):

buddy idk much as well but yes there is a way of using soundwire application for using your phone as speaker but it works only in wrt wifi.
i.e you will have to creaate hotspot through your phone connect your pc/laptop to it.
then install soundwire apk on your phone and software with dependecies on your laptop/pc and then launch application from laptop and then from your phone and by putting required details yo will be able to figure it out how to use